# PUT or POST when making idempotnet request for specific use-case

Tags: api, http, rest, restful-url

I'm designing REST API for web application.

My principles while designing API are:

- Use client *use cases* perspective rather then data model perspective. Motivation: abstract from DB schema.
- Each slash represent new use case/action.

Lets say that In the application we have users, products, locations, product-news. Use case is *user follows product-news from some location*. If location is empty then user follows news about product from each location.
The list of products and locations is well known.

#### What is the right method for adding user as a follower of a specific product-location combination?

I end up with the following URL:

```
/product/follow?product=<product_name>[&location=<location name>]
```

The `product` and `location` names are in query part because is more flexible to extend in future.

- The argument for **PUT**: Of course this request is idempotent - sending it multiple times doesn't make any other change as sending it once.
- The argument for **POST**: we don't specify URL, under which the resource is set.

Personally I'm closer to **PUT** because by the *use-case* principle for API (which I consider as the right one) the *impotency* rule seams to be the most corresponding one.

Comment: 'actions' in URIs => not REST. Simple as that really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First identify the resources. I'd say that

```
/products/<product_name>/followers
```

is the list of all users following `product_name`. You can filter using query parameters:

```
/products/<product_name>/followers?location=<location_name>
```

is the list of all users following `product_name` from `location_name`.

A `GET` request against such a resource returns a representation (JSON, XML, ...) of the list of users.

**`POST`  or `PUT`**

A `POST` request against such a resource *adds* a new user. The request body of such a `POST` request contains the details.

```
POST /products/<product_name>/followers
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "user": "some user",
  "location: "some location"
}
```

The server will respond:

```
201 Created
Location: /products/<product_name>/followers/some%20user
```

If the client knows the URI, it can use `PUT`:

```
PUT /products/<product_name>/followers/some%20user
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "location: "some location"
}
```

The server will again respond:

```
201 Created
Location: /products/<product_name>/followers/some%20user
```

**Summary**

If the client is able to exactly know the URI, you can use `PUT`. The the URL can only be known by the server, use `POST`.

Comment: Does it mean that PUT is suppose to attach final URL rather then showing its idempotence?

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment. `PUT` normally is used to create/modify a known resource. `POST` is often used to create by appending to a collection. Because of this, `PUT` is idempotent while `POST` is not.

Comment: I'd generally say that clients shouldn't be tasked with having to work out the URIs them selves. It would be better for the client to `POST` the user details to the 'followers' collection and have the server return the new URI. This way the server retains control. But of course, `POST` is not idempotent, so if a user sends the same follow request twice, two resources would be created, unless the server handles it some other way (such as rejecting the second request).